# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError

Tags: angular

I have an error message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(MarketModule)
[IndiceService -> IndiceService -> IndiceService -> IndiceService -> IndiceService]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for IndiceService! NullInjectorError: 
R3InjectorError(MarketModule)[IndiceService -> IndiceService
```

[Error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aCcf.png)

the indice.service.ts file is presented like this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { IndiceResponse } from './folder/indice.response';

@Injectable()

export class IndiceService {

  private readonly api: string = environment.api;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getIndices(): Observable<IndiceResponse> {
    return this.http.post<IndiceResponse>(this.api + `/AZEMONDL`, {
      FILTRE: {
        LASTACTIF_CODE: "1W"
      }
    });
  }

}
```

indice.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Subject, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';
import { CreateDateTimePipe } from 'src/app/shared/pipes/create-date-time.pipe';
import { Indice } from './folder/indice';
import { IndiceService } from './indice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-indice',
  templateUrl: './indice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./indice.component.css']
})
export class IndiceComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  indices: Indice[] = [];
  selectedIndex: string = '';

  indiceDatas: any;

  constructor(    
    private service: IndiceService,
    private router: Router,
    private createDateTimePipe: CreateDateTimePipe) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getIndices();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }
```

I also have a strange message for the `Router`:

```
Property 'router' is declared but its value is never read.
```

[Error Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyy9u.jpg)

indice.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PipesModule } from 'src/app/shared/pipes/pipes.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    PipesModule,
  ]
})

export class IndiceModule { }
```

I don't know where these problems come from? Thank you for your help.

Comment: about the router Router message , this message is normal as you are not using that injection at all according to the code you are pasting . better is to remove that unused injection .

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Be sure to import `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule ( {
.
.
imports: [
..HttpClientModule,
```

Answer (score 10):

The issue you are getting is because Angular doesn't know about the `IndiceService` yet.

You either have to define it at the root level:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})

export class IndiceService {...}
```

Or in your `IndiceModule` inside `providers` array:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers:[IndiceService]; //Add it to the import also above
})

export class IndiceModule { }
```

The difference between the 2 is with 'root' level service, **its single instance will be created & shared throughout the application**. While adding it in the `providers` array, its instance will be shared within this module only.

> Property 'router' is declared but its value is never read.

This error is generated by the Typescript compiler because you have injected `Router` in your `IndiceComponent`, but it is not used. So, it warns you to remove it if it is not used.

Answer (score 4):

If you have created a class just by right-click or copy pasted from somewhere, you need to add @Injectable over the class like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class IndiceService{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add providers to your componrnent:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-indice',
 templateUrl: './indice.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./indice.component.css'],
 providers: [IndiceService]
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I am not sure if this replies the original question, but it does solve my issue where I was seeing similar error after Ionic 6 removed app.module.ts file for standalone apps and this was the way how one needed to define Cordova plugins for Ionic 7 in app.component.ts file. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class IndiceService {
```

Comment: Please provide more details about your answer